# Django isn't evaluating template variables

Tags: django, jinja2

When I inspect the page I see: `post="{% url daySlots %}"`
But Im expecting to see this evaluated to: `post="/daySlots/"`
Its also ignoring other variables, the html shows the variable name like: `{{ duration }}` instead of the value like `1.5` that Im expecting.

in my views.py the html code is generated in a function like:

```
html_cal = Calendar(today.year, today.month, day_colors)

context = {
        "html_cal": mark_safe(html_cal)
}

response = render(request, "pages/book.html", context)
```

book.html looks like

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    {{ html_cal }}
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The Calendar function also has some formatted text like:
`td = f"post=\"{{% url daySlots %}}\"`

Any ideas on how to get Django to recognize the variables within the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a compiled [Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#template) to the [`{% include %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag, this way you can generate template fragments like yours and render them in another template with the current context.

```
from django.template import Template


html_cal = Calendar(today.year, today.month, day_colors)
context = {
    "html_cal": Template(html_cal)
}
response = render(request, "pages/book.html", context)
```

In your template

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    {% include html_cal %}
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thank you Iain, that worked!